# ExportAssignment in Typescript 0.9

Tags: typescript

The 0.9 Specification mentions this as a part of the module:

```
ExportAssignment: export = Identifier ;
```

However I cannot get this to compile:

```
export class Test{
    foo:number = 10; 
}

export = Test;
```

Compiling with the `--module amd` option. It gives the error:

```
tsc.js(689, 13) Microsoft JScript runtime error: please implement in derived class
```

Hopefully something simple that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you supply a link to the documentation you are looking at? The 0.9 release of TypeScript is supposed to bring the language in line with the 0.8 language specification (according to the press release).

Comment: @SteveFenton you would find it in the doc folder in the release-0.9.0-alpha branch : https://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/19cc63619d8db567718b051488db76c11285a97a#README.txt

Comment: @SteveFenton figured what it does : https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/47  look at jon's comment (the last one) for suggested syntax, And a sample project that needs it : http://gruntjs.com/getting-started#an-example-gruntfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature isn't implemented in the 0.9 Alpha Preview drop.